# How to deploy a simple "Hello world" app in avd emulator on ubuntu (without android studio)?

Tags: android, command-line, sdk, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I would like to run a simple "hello world" application in my device, how can i do that without Android Studio, on ubuntu?

I have already installed java, gradle and android sdk. I can run an android emulator from console and all works fine.
I just need to know how that works to deploy some app in my android virtual device.
What do i need to do?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.